# Extract .tbz file using .net

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, extract

I'm trying to extract a .tbz file using .net

Anyone have any suggestions?

The file will be very large (3GB) if this makes any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you'll need to know about, how to implement, or use a supporting library for [BZIP2 decompression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bzip2). Then you will need to do the same, in a different fashion, and de-archive the contents of the resulting [TAR file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar_%28file_format%29).

Answer (score 0):

You can use SharpZipLib:

http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpziplib/

However, it is licensed under the GPL, with an exception that I'm not familiar with, so you'll have to read carefully to see if it suits your needs.